# Date Operation in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a string field that containts a date in yyyy-mm-dd format.
Now, I want to get the date before that day one year later (preferred as nvarchar2). In MySQL I can do it like this:

```
select date_add(date_add(str_to_date(mydatefield,'%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 1 YEAR),INTERVAL -1 DAY) from mytable
```

How can I do that in Oracle?

And in SQL Server?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `varchar`?

Comment: Hey - I edited your last question, MsSQL is confusing (already at least one volunteer misread that as MySQL).

Comment: You (or rather, the business client) need(s) to clarify about leap years. If the input date is FEB-29-2016, what should be returned? FEB-28-2017, or FEB-27-2016? And also, if input is FEB-28-2015, should the output be FEB-27-2016 or FEB-28-2016? In both cases, `add_months()` may not return the desired result. (`add_months()` is the most natural tool for this kind of problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
select to_char(add_months(to_date(mydatefield, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1, 12), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Which gives you the previous day, one year ahead. The `- 1` is [basic date arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208). The [`add_months()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions011.htm) takes your forward a year, as that is 12 months.

The string is converted to a date with the [`to_date()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm), and back to a string using [`to_char()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions200.htm), both with suitable explicit [date format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

For example:

```
select to_char(add_months(to_date('2016-07-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1, 12), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;

TO_CHAR(AD
----------
2017-07-26

select to_char(add_months(to_date('2016-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1, 12), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;

TO_CHAR(AD
----------
2017-02-28
```

You could use intervals but they can be awkward; if the current date was 2016-03-01, subtracting a day interval and adding a year interval would give 2017-02-29, which isn't valid and would throw an error. Or if it was 2016-02-29 then adding a year first would give 2017-02-29, and it would error before you could remove the day to go back to the 28th. The `add_months()` function is non-standard but is more forgiving; though you still need to understand what it will do for edge cases.

Comment: The OP said "before" which means you should subtract 1 day, not add it. Strangely, all three answers offered so far do the same thing... really strange...

Comment: @mathguy - yes, but the code the OP showed use date_add with +1 for both the day and year intervals, at least in the first revision, so it wasn't clear which is right. That's why I referred to that, and had examples doing both. I hadn't seen they'd edited to correct that.

Comment: I see - I just looked at the edits history, and the OP changed his original post, by adding a minus sign. It wasn't there originally. This explains it.

Comment: @mathguy - yes, I'd missed that it had been edited. I've updated to remove the ambiguity. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select mydatefield,
       add_months(date_add(to_date(mydatefield,'YYYY-MM-DD')),12)+1 from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle:**

```
SELECT Add_months(TO_DATE(mydatefield, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),12)+1
FROM mytable;
```

**MSSQL:**

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1,(DATEADD(year, 1,CONVERT(datetime, mydatefield,103))) as mydate from mytable;
```